# Desmarcar todos os checkboxes ao voltar à página anterior

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo um software e percebi uma falha: quando o usuário volta a página anterior, os checkboxes continuam marcados.

Como eu desmarco todos eles?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No checkbox adicione: `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: @juniorb2ss obrigado!! resolveu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como não informou se está utilizando jquery como framework em seu projeto estou considerando que sim, caso contrário edite o código as suas necessidades

```
<input type="checkbox" checked='true' class='check' name="tecnologia" value="java"/>JAVA
<input type="checkbox" checked='true' class='check' name="tecnologia" value="html"/>HTML
<input type="checkbox" checked='true' class='check' name="tecnologia" value="css"/>CSS
<input type="checkbox" checked='true' class='check' name="tecnologia" value="javascript"/>JAVASCRIPT
```

Após a leitura do DOM executar uma função por callback para desmarcar :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".check").removeAttr("ckecked");     
}
```

lembrando que deve usar no onready para não ter chance de tentar remover o atributo checked sem ter carregado o html corretamente.

Answer (score 3):

Uma simples adição de código jQuery desmarca tudo, tanto no carregamento da página quanto em voltar à ela:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
```

Se os `checkbox` tiverem uma `class` em comum:

`$("input.class").prop('checked', false);` ou `$(".class").prop('checked', false);`

Ou pertencerem a uma `div` com um `id`:

```
$("#div input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
```

Ou num único `form` na página:

```
$("form input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
```

> Vale lembrar que os métodos `.removeAttr` e `.attr` não funcionam para
>   alterar propriedades *checked* ou *disabled* em versões mais recentes
>   do jQuery.

Comment: Sua resposta é muito detalhada `up`

Comment: @I_like_trains :D.. valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Quando a página carrega, use o código abaixo na página

### Para versão de jQuery < 1.6

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("checkbox").attr('checked', false);
});
```

### Para versão de jQuery > 1.6

```
$('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. Como restauro?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. Feito